# How can I make a SQL table from an XML file that will have a dynamic number of nodes?

Tags: sql-server, xml, openxml

I'm using SQL Server 2008.
The task: take an XML file and parse it into a(n) SQL table.
The problem: The number of columns and their names will vary based on the XML.

Here's some code:

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML;  
SET @xmlData = '<root>
  <item id="1">
    <item_number>IT23</item_number>
    <title>Item number twenty-three</title>
    <setting>5 to 20</setting>
    <parameter>10 to 16</parameter>
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <item_number>RJ12</item_number>
     <title>Another item with a 12</title>
     <setting>7 to 35</setting>
     <parameter>1 to 34</parameter>
  </item>
  <item id="3">
     <item_number>LN90</item_number>
     <title>LN with 90</title>
     <setting>3 to 35</setting>
     <parameter>9 to 50</parameter>
  </item>
</root>'
```

For example using the above XML, I would need a SQL table returned that would look like this:

[image: table snapshot]

Here's how I got the above table:

```
   DECLARE @idoc INT;
   EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xmlData

   SELECT * 
   FROM  OPENXML (@idoc, '/root/item', 2)
   WITH (item_number VARCHAR(100),
         title VARCHAR(100),
         setting VARCHAR(100),
         parameter VARCHAR(100))
```

Now let's say the XML changed where each item node had a new child node with the name 'new_node'. Like so:

```
<root>
  <item id="1">
    <item_number>IT23</item_number>
    <title>Item number twenty-three</title>
    <setting>5 to 20</setting>
    <parameter>10 to 16</parameter>
    <new_node>data</new_node>
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <item_number>RJ12</item_number>
    <title>Another item with a 12</title>
    <setting>7 to 35</setting>
    <parameter>1 to 34</parameter>
    <new_node>goes</new_node>
  </item>
  <item id="3">
    <item_number>LN90</item_number>
    <title>LN with 90</title>
    <setting>3 to 35</setting>
    <parameter>9 to 50</parameter>
    <new_node>here</new_node>
  </item>
</root>
```

I must change my code to include the new node:

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM  OPENXML (@idoc, '/root/item', 2)
   WITH (item_number VARCHAR(100),
         title VARCHAR(100),
         setting VARCHAR(100),
         parameter VARCHAR(100),
         new_node VARCHAR(100))
```

To get this table:

[image: second table from XML]

So the problem is that the child nodes of 'item' will vary.

How can I generate the same tables without specifying the columns? Is there some other approach than having to use OPENXML?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to create a SQL table from the XML, as opposed to simply storing the XML?  What will you be doing with a SQL table with an unknown set of columns that you wouldn't be able to do with XML stored in an XML data type?

Comment: This is like asking, how do I build a house if I don't know how many bedrooms I need?

Comment: Michael Fredrickson: I _will_ be storing the XML, this is just a simplified example, but in the end the table will be returned to a code-behind page that will generate an HTML table

Comment: @AaronBertrand, it's more like asking "Can you build me a house with X number of bedrooms, if I tell you what X is?" I don't think a contractor would walk away scratching their head if asked that question.
Whether there was a better way of accomplishing what I was doing in SQL is a different story :)

Comment: Why are we talking about a comment I made 21 months ago, on a question with an answer you also accepted 21 months ago?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With a dynamic number of columns you need dynamic SQL.

```
declare @XML xml = 
'<root>
  <item id="1">
    <item_number>IT23</item_number>
    <title>Item number twenty-three</title>
    <setting>5 to 20</setting>
    <parameter>10 to 16</parameter>
    <new_node>data</new_node>
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <item_number>RJ12</item_number>
    <title>Another item with a 12</title>
    <setting>7 to 35</setting>
    <parameter>1 to 34</parameter>
    <new_node>goes</new_node>
  </item>
  <item id="3">
    <item_number>LN90</item_number>
    <title>LN with 90</title>
    <setting>3 to 35</setting>
    <parameter>9 to 50</parameter>
    <new_node>here</new_node>
  </item>
</root>'

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @Col nvarchar(max) = ', T.N.value(''[COLNAME][1]'', ''varchar(100)'') as [COLNAME]' 

select @SQL = @SQL + replace(@Col, '[COLNAME]', T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname'))
from @XML.nodes('/root/item[1]/*') as T(N)

set @SQL = 'select '+stuff(@SQL, 1, 2, '')+' from @XML.nodes(''/root/item'') as T(N)' 

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@XML xml', @XML
```

Comment: I think this is one of the best bits of TSQL/XML trickery I've ever witnessed, and it solved my problem - bravo

Answer (score 2):

improving on Mikael's answer:

With a dynamic number of columns you need dynamic SQL. This code will dynamically build a select statement supporting an unknown number of nodes, including items with different node lists.

```
declare @XML xml = 
'<root>
  <item id="1">
    <item_number>IT23</item_number>
    <title>Item number twenty-three</title>
    <setting>5 to 20</setting>
    <parameter>10 to 16</parameter>
    <new_node>data</new_node>
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <item_number>RJ12</item_number>
    <title>Another item with a 12</title>
    <setting>7 to 35</setting>
    <parameter>1 to 34</parameter>
    <new_node>goes</new_node>
  </item>
  <item id="3">
    <item_number>LN90</item_number>
    <title>LN with 90</title>
    <setting>3 to 35</setting>
    <parameter>9 to 50</parameter>
    <new_node>here</new_node>
    <unique_node>test</unique_node>
  </item>
</root>'

--build an XML object with the unique list of nodes
DECLARE @xmlcolumns XML;
WITH Xml_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST('<' + node.value('fn:local-name(.)',
            'varchar(100)') + '>' AS varchar(100) ) 
         + CAST('</' + node.value('fn:local-name(.)',
            'varchar(100)') + '>' AS varchar(100) ) AS name 
    FROM @xml.nodes('/root/item/*') AS roots(node)

)

SELECT @xmlcolumns = (
SELECT CONVERT(XML,name) FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT name 
FROM Xml_CTE
) a
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('root')
)



declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @Col nvarchar(max) = ', T.N.value(''[COLNAME][1]'', ''varchar(100)'') as [COLNAME]'  

--use the unique column list xml object to build the select statement
select @SQL = @SQL + replace(@Col, '[COLNAME]', T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname'))
from @XMLcolumns.nodes('/root/*') as T(N) 

--build the entire query statement, using the original XML object as the data source
set @SQL = 'select '+stuff(@SQL, 1, 2, '')+' from @XML.nodes(''/root/item'') as T(N)' 

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@XML xml', @XML;
```